# Firestore: Delete expired documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a "user" collection which holds documents with a subcollection called "history", in which I store finished game documents. Each of these documents hold a timestamp "lastModified". What I am trying to implement is a scheduled trigger which deletes all history documents that are older than 24 hours.
Here is my attempt:

```
exports.deleteOldHistoryDocuments = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 hours").onRun(async (context) => {
    const now = Date.now();
    const cutoff = now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 hours in milliseconds

    const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection("users");
    const usersSnapshot = await usersRef.get();

    let totalDocsDeleted = 0;

    // Iterate over all user documents
    for (const userDoc of usersSnapshot.docs) {
      console.log("current documents schedule: ");
      const historyRef = userDoc.ref.collection("history");
      const historySnapshot = await historyRef.where("lastModified", "<", cutoff).get();
      const numDocsDeleted = historySnapshot.size;

      if (numDocsDeleted > 0) {
        const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
        historySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          batch.delete(doc.ref);
        });

        await batch.commit();

        console.log("Deleted ${numDocsDeleted} history documents for user ${userDoc.id}");
        totalDocsDeleted += numDocsDeleted;
      }
    }

    console.log("Total documents deleted: " + totalDocsDeleted);
  });
```

The problem with the above code is that the historySnapshot query result in 0 documents, even though I made sure that documents with a timestamp older than 24 hours exist. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Try the query builder in the firestore console and check if the query returns the desired results.

Comment: Also, It would be helpful if you provided with a sample data or at least the Schema. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use [Firestore's built-in TTL policies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl) for this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh wow that makes everything way easier and cleaner! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the field `lastModified` in the history collection is of type `TimeStamp` in the firestore.

Based on that,

If you want to query a TimeStamp, you need a JS `Date` Obj. `Date.now()` returns a number which you are using to subtract 24Hrs. All you need to do now is to convert that number back to Date obj.

Changing this line should do the trick.

```
let cutOff = new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. However, using Firestore's built-in TTL policies as Frank suggested is probably the way to go.

Comment: @DanielBrunner Yeah, TTL is for sure better for your use case. But, this might help you at other TimeStamp queries in the future.